# ASP.Net MVC individual (identity) authorization based on role id not working

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using individual authentication in ASP.Net MVC 5.

I seed the "Admin" user in the context along with a password "12345678" and it's role "Owner".
As in here:

```
if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Owner"))
{
    var rolestore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
    var rolemanager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(rolestore);
    var role = new IdentityRole {Name = "Owner"};

    rolemanager.Create(role);
    if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "Admin"))
    {
        var userstore = new UserStore<AppUser>(context);
        var usermanager = new UserManager<AppUser>(userstore);
        var user = new AppUser()
        {
            UserName = "Admin",
            PasswordHash = usermanager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword("12345678"),
            Role = "Owner"
        };

            usermanager.Create(user);
            usermanager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Owner");
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
I need to use role-based authentication in my app but when I use [Authorize(Roles = "Owner")] I'm redirected to the login page.

But using either [Authorize] or [Authorize (Users = "Admin")] work fine, but I need the role-based authentication to work.

**Troubleshooting that I've done so far:**
1- Enabling the lazy-loading in the context `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;`
2- Removing the `<remove name="RoleManager"/>`from Web.config
3- Making sure the database to see if the Admin is related to the Owner role
[image]
4- Logging out and logging in again to reset the cookie

Yet it's interesting that `[Authorize(Roles = "Owner")]` isn't working. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Can you make sure the cookie that contains the auth certificate comes with a claim that contains the role in the certificate?

Authorize would only read your auth certificate and try to figure out whether there are any roles mentioned or not. If your auth cookie doesn't contain any information on the roles of the authenticated user, it wont really work. :)

Comment: You were right. I didn't properly store the role in the cookie :( I nearly wasted two days working on this problem. Thank you very very very much @SwagataPrateek

Comment: Happy to help. :) Looks like now I should've posted that as an answer.

Comment: @SwagataPrateek Then you should go ahead and post it as the answer!  ;) You helped me solve this man. So post your answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Hi @Ali, I already added my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you kindly make sure the cookie that contains the auth certificate comes with a claim that contains the role in the certificate?

`Authorize` would only read your auth certificate and try to figure out whether there are any roles mentioned or not. If your auth cookie doesn't contain any information on the roles of the authenticated user, it wont really work. :)